# Passing selected option's value to another component in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-props

I'm new to nextjs/react so bare with me here. In my project I have multiple select elements with multiple options in each one. When an option is selected or changed I want to pass that value to another component. I was able to pass an onClick event to another component but when I tried a similar solution I wasn't able to get it to work. So the select elements are being mapped in Component A2, but the options for those elements are also being mapped in Component A3 and I need to pass the value to Component B2. You will see in my code I tried to pass it with the "handleOnChange". I'm not very good at explaining things so here is my code snippets, I hope this makes sense:

Parent Component

```
export default function Post({ globalProps, page, globalPages, sidebarProps }) {
  const [addFlexItem, setAddFlexItem] = useState(false)
  const [addFlexItemStyles, setFlexItemStyles] = useState()
  
  return (
    <Layout globalProps={globalProps}>
      <main className={styles.container}>
        <FlexSidebar sidebarProps={sidebarProps} onClick={() => setAddFlexItem(true)} handleOnChange={() => setFlexItemStyles()} />
        <FlexContainer addFlexItem={addFlexItem} addFlexItemStyles={addFlexItemStyles} />
      </main>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

---

Component A1

```
const FlexSidebar = ({ sidebarProps, onClick, handleOnChange }) => {
return (
    <aside className={styles.left_sidebar}>
      <section className={styles.wrap}>
        {/* we are padding the onClick to the child component */}
        {container === true && <FlexSidebarContainer sidebarProps={sidebarProps} onClick={onClick} handleOnChange={handleOnChange} />}
        {items === true && <FlexSidebarItems sidebarProps={sidebarProps} />}
      </section>
    </aside>
  )
}
```

Component A2

```
const FlexSidebarContainer = ({ sidebarProps, onClick, handleOnChange }) => {
  const options = sidebarProps.options

  return (
    <>
      <p className={styles.warning}>{sidebarProps.containerWarningText}</p>
      <button type="button" className="btn" onClick={() => onClick()}>
        {sidebarProps.addItemBtn}
      </button>
      <form className={styles.form}>
        {options.map((option, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={index} className={styles.form_item}>
              <div className={styles.form_label_wrap}>
                <label>{option.title}</label>
              </div>
              <FlexSidebarSelect options={option.items} handleOnChange={handleOnChange} />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </form>
    </>
  )
}
```

Component A3

```
const FlexSidebarSelect = ({ options, handleOnChange }) => {

  return (
    <div className={styles.form_item_wrap}>
      <select onChange={(value) => handleOnChange(value)}>
        {options.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <option key={index} value={item.value}>{item.item}</option>
          )
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Component B1

```
const FlexContainer = ({ addFlexItem, addFlexItemStyles }) => {

  return (
    <section className={styles.right_content}>
      <FlexItem addFlexItem={addFlexItem} addFlexItemStyles={addFlexItemStyles} />
    </section>
  )
}
```

Component B2

```
const FlexItem = ({ addFlexItem, addFlexItemStyles }) => {
  const [isaddFlexItem, setaddFlexItem] = useState(addFlexItem)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setaddFlexItem(addFlexItem)
  }, [addFlexItem])

  return (
    isaddFlexItem ?
      <div className={styles.flex_item}>
        <div className={styles.flex_item_wrap}>
          <div className={styles.flex_item_inner}>
          </div>
          <button className={styles.trash}>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    : "empty"
  )
}
```

I will add that if I change the code in Component A3 to this, im able to log the value, but I cant get it to work in the parent component.

```
const FlexSidebarSelect = ({ options, handleOnChange }) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("")

  const handleOptionChange = (e) => {
    let value = e.target.value
    setValue({
      value
    })
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.form_item_wrap}>
      <select onChange={handleOptionChange}>
        {options.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <option key={index} value={item.value}>{item.item}</option>
          )
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```